# Python 2.7 and PrettyTables

Tags: python-2.7, computer-forensics

I am trying to get PrettyTables to work with the following script.  I can get it almost to look right but it keeps separating my tables so it is printing 16 separate tables.  I need all information in one table that I can sort.  I appreciate all the help i can get.

```
import sys
import os
import datetime
import hashlib
import logging

def getScanPath(): #12
# Prompt User for path to scan
    path = raw_input('Please enter the directory to scan:  ')

# Verify that the path is a directory
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        return path
    else:
        sys.exit('Invalid File Path ... Script Aborted')

def getFileList(filePath):
# Create an empty list to hold the resulting files
    pathList =[]
# Get a list of files, note these will be just the names of the files
# NOT the full path
    simpleFileNameList = os.listdir(filePath)

# Now process each filename in the list 
    for eachFile in simpleFileNameList:
    # 1) Get the full path by join the directory with the filename
        fullPath = os.path.join(filePath, eachFile)
    # 2) Make sure the full path is an absolute path
        absPath = os.path.abspath(fullPath)
    # 3) Make sure the absolute path is a file i.e. not a folder or directory 
        if os.path.isfile(absPath):
        # 4) if all is well, add the absolute path to the list
            pathList.append(absPath)

        else:
            logging.error('A Non-File has been identified')

# 5) Once all files have been identified, return the list to the caller 
    return pathList 

def getFileName(theFile):
    return os.path.basename(theFile)
def getFileSize(theFile):
    return os.path.getsize(theFile)
def getFileLastModified(theFile):
    return os.path.getmtime(theFile)
def getFileHash(theFile):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(theFile, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()

 # Main Script Starts Here

 if __name__ == '__main__':
#Welcome Message
    print "\nWelcome to the file scanner\n"

# prompt user for directory path
    scanPath = getScanPath()

# Get a list of files with full path
    scanFileList = getFileList(scanPath)

# Output Filenames
    print "Files found in directory"
    for eachFilePath in scanFileList:
        fileName      = getFileName(eachFilePath)
        fileSize      = getFileSize(eachFilePath)
        lastModified  = getFileLastModified(eachFilePath)
        hashValue     = getFileHash(eachFilePath)
        fileModified  = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(lastModified))

        from prettytable import PrettyTable

        pTable = PrettyTable()

        pTable.field_names = ["File Name", "File Size", "Last Modified", "Md5 Hash Value"]

        pTable.add_row ([fileName, fileSize, fileModified, hashValue])

        print (pTable)enter code here
```

This should show me one big table using all the values from a set directory that the user chooses.  This will allow me to sort the table later using prettytables.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with prettyTables, but I noticed you have `lastModified` and `fileModified` yet only `fileModified` is used for a column in your table. Are you sure pretty table doesn't have some kind of row limit?